# Analyzing javascript performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

I have a web application that has a lot of JavaScript code.
As the content gets larger, some of the features start to get slower.

I can't seem to find out what is exactly taking too much time and freezes the browser for a second or two.

Currently, I am putting `Date` variables at different locations and subtracting them to see the parts that take too much time, but It is not helping me a lot.

I am aware of Chrome's Developer toolbar and firebug, but I don't know exactly how to use them to see processing time of codes and such...

Please help me to optimize my app and figure out where it chokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For chrome dev toolbar press f12

- go to network tab to see dl times.
- And sources tab to debug code.
- And profiles tab to record cpu usage

Or google for tutorials and just try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`console.time()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.time)

For instance:

```
console.time('yourFunction');

//Time what you'd like inbetween the statements
yourFunction();

console.timeEnd('yourFunction');
```

Alternatively (although you mentioned you've already used these), you can try the following native functions:
[date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
[getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)
[getMilliseconds()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds)